# Cron ran sql does not spool to file

Tags: shell, oracle11g, cron

Running a sql script from sh works fine. The sql script only writes (in this simplified case) a date to a spool file.

When running the file from cron it does not spool however.

the sh (testsql.sh):

```
    #! /bin/sh
. /private/someuser/.bashrc
setenv PATH $PATH:/usr/kerberos/bin:.:/local/bin:/....
/prog/oracle/10.2.0/bin/sqlplus someuser/somepw@p208 @/project/myfullpath/OW_Server_list_SIS.sql
```

the sql script (OW_Server_list_SIS.sql):

```
spool /project/myfullpath/SIS_Server_list.txt
select sysdate from dual;
spool off;
```

I have following line in crontab of myuser:

```
36,15 * * * * env USER=someuser /project/myfullpath/testsql.sh
```

So a manual run of testsql.sh writes to SIS_Server_list.txt, but cron does not.

As you can see I have tried adding the environment to cron and the profile to the sh and also copied the path as used by myuser in. These are all the remedies I came across online but nothing works so far. I am on redhat 6. Surely it has to do with environments but I am pooped out with respect to that. All these lines added (i.e. bashrc/setenv/path) I also tried having commented out the others. Any new ideas would be appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Is it actually running - are you getting output from cron showing the SQL\*Plus session banner and date? If so that would show if the spool was erroring.

Comment: I assume it is not running at all. However spooling to file would only be from where I command it to spool and cron doesn't output to screen.

Comment: Cron usually sends an email on failure though, which would include the output. You could also redirect the output from the script and/or crontab entry, but I'd look for email on the server first.

Comment: I'm not sure where to pick that up. Though I will have a go at redirecting stderr. For now I just solved it going from sh to csh. Not sure how that matters but maybe I will find out when I have the time to look at stderr

Comment: Perhaps your csh environment is picking up the Oracle environment variables properly, and you just need to explicitly set them with sh, in the script. I wanted to see the cron output before suggesting that as an answer though.